# Intercambio de valores en laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

Trato de hacer lo siguiente:

Usuario1: Pasa 50 Monedas a usuario dos

Solo tengo una tabla que es la user

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('monto')->default('0');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Este es el formulario de envio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven solo hay un select para seleccionar el usuario a pasar el 'stock' por asi llamarlo

Este es mi formulario

```
<form action="{{route('transaccion')}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <label>user receiver:</label>
        <select name="id_receptor" id="" required value="Usuario Receptor" style="align-items: center;">
          @foreach($usuarios as $User)
          <option value="{{ $User['id'] }}">{{ $User['name'] }}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
        <br>
      <label for="">Money: </label>
      <input type="number" name="monto">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
```

Con este codigo pienso hacer el envio

```
public function transaccion(request $request){
    $product = User::where('id', '=', $request->id_receptor)->first();
    if ($product) {
        $product->update(["monto" => $product->monto + $request->monto]);
        return back();
     }
     else{
         return 'Hubo un error';
     }
}
```

Mi problema es que no me da error pero tampoco se actualiza el stock del usuario Receptor

Gracias

Comment: Verifica y posterior agrégalo a tu pregunta si recibes la data del `$request` por medio de `dd`